# Number of badges reported by Area 51 or SEDE doesn't equal flair image

Tags: bug, badges, badge-progress, combined-flair

At Area 51 my 'live update' (6th in the right column on my ["Definition" tab, for a beta site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106955?phase=definition) that I followed) says I have 1 gold, 53 silver and 269 bronze badges.

[image: Area 51 Definition]

My [Flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/4485506/rob?tab=flair) Badge (updated today) says I have: 1 gold, 52 silver and 263 bronze badges.

[image: Flair Badge]

If I run this SEDE Query: "[Total # of badges by 'color', for a single user networkwide](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/897214/total-of-badges-by-color-for-a-single-user-networkwide)" it says I have 1 gold, 71 silver and 437 bronze badges.

That's in agreement for gold, but 19 silver and 174 bronze badges more than my global flair (and not accounted for by adding sites with less than 200 reputation).

It's not impossible that the extra badges for the SEDE count are duplicates, but I thought global flair has dupes included. Not sure why the Area 51 count is far ahead either, since my global flair badge updated today.

It would be preferable (correct?) if the Area 51 count was used, or is SEDE closest?

---

After [Rene's SEDE Reputation Calculation](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/897214/total-of-badges-by-color-for-a-single-user-networkwide) was proofread by Glorfindel I re-ran it yesterday and a few minutes ago (updated 18 hours ago) with these results:

Data updated Sep 09 at 8:20 - 
Reputation: 18553
No. of Badges: 324
Gold: 1
Silver: 55
Bronze: 268

Data updated Sep 16 at 1:40 - 
Reputation: 18887
No. of Badges: 333
Gold: 1
Silver: 55
Bronze: 277

Area 51 reports:

[image: Area 51]

Flair Image:

[image: Flair Image]

According to my Achievements Feed I earned 2 bronze badges yesterday and none in the prior several days. Our Flair images remain behind all other calculations of its value.

Running the above test on a different user, 251740, shows an [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/118484/mainframes) of 261K, 62, 789 and 1938, a [Flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/251740/rory-alsop?tab=flair) image of 245k, 56, 761, 1.8k, and [Rene's query](https://data.stackexchange.com/space/query/898502/badge-count-across-the-network-to-match-what-is-in-your-flair?accountid=4485506) of 252293, 2694, 59, 775 and 1860.

Proof that the Flair image is lower for other users too.

Comment: I see it is last updated on Sep 9 at 8:20. UTC

Comment: @NogShine - Yes, SEDE is fairly old yet way ahead; since badges can't be lost the higher number is true (after deducting under 200 reputation site badges from the SEDE calculation). Do you have a link to a SEDE query that calculates the same way that the flair image is derived?

Comment: I think the SEDE query implements a different functional requirement. This query shows a result that is much closer to what you see in your flair: https://data.stackexchange.com/space/query/898502/twt?accountid=4485506

Comment: @rene - Thanks for confirming. That query uses old data, despite that it's still higher.

Comment: @rene - BTW: If you're interested in improving that query - it looks hardwired for one user (unlike [Glorfindel's query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/897214/total-of-badges-by-color-for-a-single-user-networkwide)), doesn't include the site area51,  hopefully (for others, I don't have over 200 there), it includes places with odd names like https://mathoverflow.net/, and hidden communities are being tallied (which wouldn't occur with the flair badge image). The SEDE database should get a bump tomorrow, but then the numbers will be even higher and farther out of whack.

Comment: Rene's query can be adjusted (now). Area 51 is not included in SEDE and I doubt it's included in the flair. MathOverflow is a special Stack Exchange site, no doubt, but less special than e.g. Stack Apps. Information about hidden communities is also not available in SEDE.

Comment: @Glorfindel - Thanks. Rene's query (4 comments up) included one of my hidden communities (ell). That query contains this line: `where u.accountid = ', ##accountid:int?4485506## ,'` that appears to be user specific.

Comment: Yes, but that's just a default value for the parameter, to make it easier for you. There's a field to change it while running the query.

Comment: Note that SEDE includes old sites which aren't around anymore, such as [productivity.se] and [startups.se]. I think those are excluded from the flair.

Comment: @Glorfindel - I guess that's another tweak that should be made to Rene's query to make the result exact. In **my** case I've not joined anywhere that was closed where badges were earned, so I wouldn't have SEDE results returned for ghost sites. It doesn't seem like Rory's large discrepancy is accounted for by PP, where he was a member.