# Why do the network accounts not match up for many users? (it's not hidden accounts)

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-accounts, network-profile

Consider [this user's **MetaSE profile**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214/sonic-the-wizard-werehog?tab=topactivity). It **shows he has 113 Network accounts**:
[image: User1 accnts section]

But [his **network profile**](https://stackexchange.com/users/2477436/gparyani?tab=accounts) only lists 107 accounts:
[image: User1 network profile]

(You can get a count of accounts by running `$(".account-container").length` from the console on a network profile page.)

The [**API lists 112 accounts**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#page=1&pagesize=100&ids=2477436&types=main_site&filter=!*LCuZZRrnwsL79P_&run=true), which is proper once you factor in that the API doesn't do *Area 51* at all.

Note that all the users in this question were chosen because (A) they have a lot of accounts and (B) **none of them are hidden** (a moderator can tell).

Comparing the API to the web page, the following, not hidden, accounts are missing from said web page:

- https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/5977/
- https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/66598/
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/63851/
- https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/20692/
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/56374/
- https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/32209/

There's nothing obviously different about them.  (Seem to be mainly just for flagging spam).

---

Another [user has 163 accounts on his MetaSE profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene?tab=topactivity), but his [network profile only lists 162](https://stackexchange.com/users/281857/rene?tab=accounts).  Using the API<sup>(Code below)</sup>, it seems that **he really has 164 accounts** and these are missing from his network profile (and not hidden):

- https://iot.stackexchange.com/users/6273/
- https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/4448/

Again, these don't appear to be special.

There are several other users with discrepancies. So, the questions are:

#### 1) Why does the number of accounts shown on many user's site profiles not match the number of accounts on the user's network profile?

#### 2) Why are random accounts, that are not hidden, not shown on many user's network profiles?

#### 3) Why does the number of accounts shown on many user's site profiles not seem correct given the accounts listed in the API? (after correcting for hidden accounts and the *Area 51* omission)

---

---

I used 2 code snippits for quick and dirty account compares.

This one is run on **network profile, *accounts* tabs:**

```
var sqlch = $(".account-container").each ( (J, node) => {
    var siteLnk = $(node).children ("a");
    console.log (siteLnk[0].href);
} );
```

This one is run from the browser console on almost any old page<sup>(It calls the API)</sup>:

```
var usrNetId    = 2477436;
var myKey       = "";  //  "&key=3TIJ...(";  // key is optional
getPageOfAccnts (1);
function getPageOfAccnts (pageNum) {
    fetch (
        `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/${usrNetId}/associated?page=${pageNum}&pagesize=100&types=main_site&filter=!*LCuZZRrnwsL79I2${myKey}`
    )
    .then (function (response) {
        if (response.ok)  return response.json();
        throw new Error (`API problem: Error ${response.status}, ${response.statusText}`);
    } )
    .then (function (rJsn) {
        if (rJsn.backoff  ||  rJsn.error_id) {
            throw new Error (`From API: Backoff ${rJsn.backoff}, Error: ${rJsn.error_id}, ${rJsn.error_message}, ${rJsn.error_name}`);
        }
        console.log (`Quota remaining: ${rJsn.quota_remaining}; Items found: ${rJsn.items.length}`);

        let uAccounts = rJsn.items;
        console.log ("\n-User's accounts:\n-----------------");
        for (let zAccnt of uAccounts) {
            console.log (`${zAccnt.site_url}/users/${zAccnt.user_id}/`, zAccnt.user_type);
        }
        if (rJsn.has_more) {
            let newPageNm   = rJsn.page + 1;
            if (newPageNm < 10)  getPageOfAccnts (newPageNm);  // sanity check.
        }
    } );
};
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many accounts does each user's Area 51 account's "accounts" tab say the user has?

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog, in your case, 101?!?  Not sure what's going on there and let's call that a separate issue. ... PS:  101 may be a design limit for that tab on Area 51.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles Worthy question, I've been studying this for 2 hours and have no answer either. I can tell you that [badge counts don't match](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315480/number-of-badges-reported-by-area-51-or-sede-doesnt-equal-flair-image) either - things aren't always counted correctly, but that's not a satisfying answer. I forced a recalculation on a half dozen of my accounts a few days ago, and scored a few hundred flair (visible on A51) for my trouble. My Flair Badge scored partial credits (I gained more Badges than I received Notifications for, or 'main SE activity')

Comment: The profiles are messed up and are not mapped to the network account correctly. If I recall correctly, there was a bug a while ago that caused a lot of these to pop up. It was fixed to stop causing them but I don't think anyone ever cleaned up the unmapped profiles.

Comment: Possibly related: [Reputation sync from main to meta is stalled](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/325811) (maybe another scheduled job just died *again*)

Comment: @MetaBugWizard Not related. The problem here occurs when the profile is created or more commonly on account merges. Only manual intervention can fix it.